# $.post syntax with array get variables

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to pass an arrary using GET like you typically would in the browser by doing

```
val[]=whatever&val[]=secondwhater....
```

I'm wondering what the equivalent syntax is for jquery because I keep getting errors when I do this:

```
com[]:(one),com[]:(two),com[]:(three),com[]:(four),com[]:(five),com[]:(six),com[]:(seven)
```

Comment: Can you post the sample code that you are working with>

Comment: are you encoding them?

Comment: doing what? How are you doing that?

Comment: Construct the array prior to passing it to the ajax function; then pass it along as a value to a key `val[] = whatever; val[] = somethingelse` then in ajax `{ data : val }`, then access it like an array on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass an array as data, eg

```
$.post(url, {
    val: ['whatever', 'secondwhater']
});
```

This will send the following in the POST data

```
val[]: whatever
val[]: secondwhater
```

or in its raw form

```
val%5B%5D=whatever&val%5B%5D=secondwhater
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will serialize arrays for you using [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) helper function. So it is enough to do this:

```
jQuery.post(
    '/some_url',
    {
        'com': [
            '(one)', '(two)', '(three)', '(four)', '(five)', '(six)', '(seven)'
        ]
    }
);
```

See demo for sending this request (just watch the browser's console): http://jsfiddle.net/VebZk/